# Red-Black Tree Insertion CLRS

Tags: c++, binary-tree, red-black-tree

The algorithm described in CLRS 3 ed. looks wrong. I tried implement but the insertion not works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

const char BLACK = 'B';
const char RED = 'R';

template <class T>
class Node{

    public:
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        Node *parent;
        char color;
        T key;

        Node(T x){
            this->left = NULL;
            this->right = NULL;
            this->parent = NULL;
            this->key = x;
            this->color = RED;
        };

        virtual ~Node(){};
};

template <class T>
class RedBlackTree{

    private:

        int ammount;
        int h;
        int lastAmmount;
        Node<T> *root;
        Node<T> *NIL;

        void destroy_node(Node<T> *&node);
        Node<T> *remove_node(Node<T> *&node, T x);  // not imeplemented yet
        Node<T> *search_node(Node<T> *&node, T x);  // not imeplemented yet

        void printInfo(Node<T> *&x);
        void printInOrder_node(Node<T> *&node);

        void printInLevel_node(Node<T> *&node, int level);
        int calculeHeight(Node<T> *&node);

        void rotateLeft(Node<T> *&x);
        void rotateRight(Node<T> *&y);
        void insertFixUp(Node<T> *&x);


    public:

        RedBlackTree();
        virtual ~RedBlackTree();
        void destroy();

        void insert(T x);
        void remove(T x);       // not imeplemented yet
        Node<T> *search(T x);   // not implemented yet

        int height();
        void printInOrder();
        void printInLevel();
};


template <class T>
RedBlackTree<T>::RedBlackTree(){

    this->ammount = 0;
    this->lastAmmount = -1;
    this->h = 0;

    this->NIL = new Node<T>(-1);
    this->NIL->color = BLACK;
    this->NIL->left = this->NIL->right = this->NIL->parent = this->NIL;


    this->root = this->NIL;
    this->root->color = BLACK;
}

template <class T>
RedBlackTree<T>::~RedBlackTree(){
    delete this->root;
}



template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::destroy_node(Node<T> *&node){
    if(node != NULL){
        this->destroy(node->left);
        this->destroy(node->right);
        delete node;
    }
}

template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::destroy(){
    this->destroy_node(this->root);
}





// RB methods
template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::rotateLeft(Node<T> *&x){

    Node<T> *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;

    if(y->left != this->NIL)
        y->left->parent = x;

    y->parent = x->parent;

    if(x->parent == this->NIL)
        this->root = y;
    else if(x == x->parent->left)
        x->parent->left = y;
    else
        x->parent->right = y;

    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;
}


template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::rotateRight(Node<T> *&y){

    Node<T> *x = y->left;
    y->left = x->right;

    if(x->right != this->NIL)
        x->right->parent = y;

    x->parent = y->parent;

    if(y->parent == this->NIL)
        this->root = x;
    else if(y == y->parent->left)
        y->parent->left = x;
    else
        y->parent->right = x;

    x->right = y;
    y->parent = x;
}


template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::insertFixUp(Node<T> *&z){


    Node<T> *y;

    while(z != this->root and z->parent->color == RED){
        if(z->parent == z->parent->parent->left){
            y = z->parent->parent->right;
            if(y->color == RED){
                z->parent->color = BLACK;
                y->color = BLACK;
                z->parent->parent->color = RED;
                z = z->parent->parent;
            }
            else{
                if(z == z->parent->right){
                    z = z->parent;
                    this->rotateLeft(z);
                }

                z->parent->color = BLACK;
                z->parent->parent->color = RED;
                this->rotateRight(z->parent->parent);
            }
        }
        else{
            y = z->parent->parent->left;
            if(y->color == RED){
                z->parent->color = BLACK;
                y->color = BLACK;
                z->parent->parent->color = RED;
                z = z->parent->parent;
            }
            else{
                if(z == z->parent->left){
                    z = z->parent;
                    this->rotateRight(z);
                }

                z->parent->color = BLACK;
                z->parent->parent->color = RED;
                this->rotateLeft(z->parent->parent);
            }
        }
    }


    this->root->color = BLACK;

}



template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::insert(T val){

    Node<T> *z = new Node<T>(val);
    Node<T> *x = this->root;
    Node<T> *y = this->NIL;

    while(x != this->NIL){
        y = x;
        if(z->key < x->key)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }


    z->parent = y;

    if(y == this->NIL)
        this->root = z;
    else if(z->key < y->key)
        y->left = z;
    else
        y->right = z;


    z->left = this->NIL;
    z->right = this->NIL;
    z->color = RED;

    this->insertFixUp(z);
}





template <class T>
int RedBlackTree<T>::height(){

    if(this->lastAmmount == this->ammount)
        return this->h;

    this->h = this->calculeHeight(this->root);
    this->lastAmmount = this->ammount;
    return this->h;
}


template <class T>
int RedBlackTree<T>::calculeHeight(Node<T> *&node){
    if(node == this->NIL)
        return 0;

    int l_h = this->calculeHeight(node->left);
    int r_h = this->calculeHeight(node->right);

    if(l_h > r_h)
        return l_h+1;

    return r_h+1;
}



template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::printInfo(Node<T> *&x){
    cout << "key=";
    cout << x->key;

    cout << "  l->key=";
    if( x->left == this->NIL) 
        cout << "N";
    else 
        cout << x->left->key;

    cout << "  r->key=";
    if( x->right == this->NIL) 
        cout << "N";
    else 
        cout << x->right->key;

    cout << "  p->key=";
    if( x->parent == this->NIL) 
        cout << "N";
    else 
        cout << x->parent->key;

    cout << "  color=" << x->color << endl;
}

template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::printInOrder_node(Node<T> *&node){
    if(node != this->NIL){
        this->printInOrder_node(node->left);
        //cout << " " << node->key;
        this->printInfo(node);
        this->printInOrder_node(node->right);
    }
}

template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::printInOrder(){
    this->printInOrder_node(this->root);
}



template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::printInLevel(){
    int h = this->height();
    for(int i=1; i<=h; i++)
        this->printInLevel_node(this->root, i);
}


template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::printInLevel_node(Node<T> *&node, int level){
    if(node == this->NIL)
        return;

    if(level == 1)
        this->printInfo(node); //cout << node->key << " ";
    else if(level > 1){
        this->printInLevel_node(node->left, level-1);
        this->printInLevel_node(node->right, level-1);
    }
}





int main(){


    RedBlackTree<int> *bt = new RedBlackTree<int>();

    int v[9] = {11, 2, 14, 1, 7, 15, 5, 8, 4};
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
        int x = v[i];
        cout << x << " ";
        bt->insert(x);
    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "In Level:" << endl; 
    bt->printInLevel();
    cout << endl;



    delete bt;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to find some others explanations in previous topics, but not seems to work.
This code is basically equals the pseudocode of the book. The expected result for the *main* example is *in level*:

```
       7
     /   \
   2      11
 /  \    /  \
1    5  8    14
    /         \
   4           15
```

So, what's wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: CLRS is very widely used so it is unlikely that there is an error in the text. Figure 13.4 shows the steps that occur as the newly inserted node is moved up the tree. You could try having your program print out the tree at each step in order to compare and isolate the error in your code.

Comment: A [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Consider what happens when you add the second node. You start with this:

```
11 (black)
```

then add the new node:

```
  11 (black)
 /
2 (red)
```

then then try to fix it up:

```
template <class T>
void RedBlackTree<T>::insertFixUp(Node<T> *&z){
  Node<T> *y;

  while(z != this->root and z->parent->color == RED){
    ...
  }
this->root->color = BLACK;
}
```

Note that since `11` is black to begin with, control never enters the loop, so the call to `insertFixUp` does nothing. So you're left with a tree with a red leaf, which is not a valid red-black tree. After that, if your code expects to be working on a valid red-black tree, it's liable to go wrong.

There may be other bugs, but you should try to get the two-node tree working before you attempt to add a third node.

Comment: I don't think so. Build the example in this demo: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RedBlack.html.
Furthermore, the leafs are blacks, once as every leaf is the NIL node (a black node).

Comment: @meitcher: The example in that demo cannot change the validity of the code in your question, and if you call the node pointed to by `NIL` a leaf, then your data structure is *not a tree at all.*

Comment: I don't understand why is _not a tree at all_. The NIL is just a sentinel (as said in the book). 

See this picture: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Red-black_tree_example.svg/2000px-Red-black_tree_example.svg.png. 
The NIL is considered a leaf.

Comment: "Note that since 11 is black to begin with, control never enters the loop" What are you talking about? The `z` is the `red` node contains `2`, not `11`.

Comment: By the definition in CLRS, 3ed, the those `NIL` pointer is defined to be blac, and by this definition it is impossible add a red leaf.